# how to add duration to mjpeg or how to make mjpeg faster

Tags: ffmpeg, encode, duration, mjpeg, ffprobe

i have ip-cam mjpeg that i made and it have total 240 frames

encode souce is
**ffmpeg.exe -framerate 25 -i c:\%06d.jpg\ -s 1920x1080 -qscale 1 -vcodec mjpeg -r 25  C:\result.mjpg -y**

now i want to play result.mjpg by mjpeg player i made

```
my problem
1. i can't get mjpeg's play time or duration time

2. playing is slower then other movie player so i want to sync it and play more faster
```

below is ffprobe result

```
Input #0, mjpeg, from 'result.mjpg':
Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg), 1920x1080, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 25 tbc
```

below is result added -show_frame

```
[FRAME]
media_type=video
key_frame=1
pkt_pts=720000
pkt_pts_time=0.600000
pkt_dts=720000
pkt_dts_time=0.600000
best_effort_timestamp=720000
best_effort_timestamp_time=0.600000
pkt_duration=48000
pkt_duration_time=0.040000
pkt_pos=4731406
pkt_size=313289
width=1920
height=1080
pix_fmt=yuvj444p
sample_aspect_ratio=333:320
pict_type=I
coded_picture_number=0
display_picture_number=0
interlaced_frame=0
top_field_first=0
repeat_pict=0
[/FRAME]
```

ffprobe show me there are Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A

how do i set Duration and bitrate 
is there any encode-option  i have to set ?

when i decode mjpeg  like below

i can't get duration just 0

```
AVFormatContext*  pFC;
int               ret;

pFC = avformat_alloc_context();

ret  = avformat_open_input(&pFC, filename, NULL, NULL);
if (ret < 0) {
    // fail .
}

ret  = avformat_find_stream_info(pFC, NULL);
if (ret < 0) {
    // fail
}
printf("duration %ld", pFC->duration);   <----- only 0
```

Answer (score 0):

i changed option fromn SWS_BICUBIC to SWS_FAST_BILINEAR
it seems like faster and my question 2 is done

```
static int sws_flags = SWS_BICUBIC;
struct SwsContext *img_convert_ctx;
img_convert_ctx = sws_getContext(   pVCtx->width, 
                                    pVCtx->height,
                                    pVCtx->pix_fmt,
                                    pVCtx->width, 
                                    pVCtx->height,
                                    PixelFormat::PIX_FMT_BGR24,
                                    sws_flags, NULL, NULL, NULL)


static int sws_flags = SWS_FAST_BILINEAR;
struct SwsContext *img_convert_ctx;
img_convert_ctx = sws_getContext(   pVCtx->width, 
                                    pVCtx->height,
                                    pVCtx->pix_fmt,
                                    pVCtx->width, 
                                    pVCtx->height,
                                    PixelFormat::PIX_FMT_BGR24,
                                    sws_flags, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```